# Troubleshooting help: YouTube videos won't play on Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, video, youtube

I just got a new Windows 10 PC & I'm finding that it won't play YouTube videos. Specifically YouTube. In the video area the loading indicator circles indefinitely and I see this message...

> If playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device

**Additional info & steps I've tried...**

- Netflix plays flawlessly
- Other Macs, PCs, iOS & Android devices on the same network play YouTube videos no problem
- I restarted the machine
- Restarted the cable modem
- The machine can do other Internet stuff fine -- browse websites, email, etc.
- I cleared the browser cache & browsing data
- I tried a different browser (I tried Chrome & MS Edge)
- I looked under "Windows Defender Security Center > App & browser control" but I don't see anything there about blocking videos.
- Turned off ad blocker
- Tried connecting via Ethernet and wi-fi
- No peripherals connected to the machine

**System info**

Gigabyte Aero 15x
Windows 10 Pro
Version 1803
Installed on 8/14/2018
OS build 17134.228

Any help, advice, or further troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** updated the Intel Graphics driver